# Binary search not return true in first iteration of while loop when target == list[mid]

Tags: java, arrays, element, binary-search

I thought I was an expert of binary search because i can do it linear, recursive and iterative but i cant even get this to work in java

so if i set my target variable to equal the mid point, my if statement skips over that and moves on to else if

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99 };
        int target = 44;
        System.out.print(BinarySearchIterarive(list, target));

    }

    public static boolean BinarySearchIterarive(int[] list, int target) {
        int high = list.length - 1;
        int low = 0;
        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (target == list[mid]) {
                      return true;
            } else if (target < list[mid]) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else {
                low = mid + 1;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It just skips over my if statement of

```
if (target ==list[mid])
```

when list[mid]is 44

Comment: vs studio debugger it does not return true after it executes the if statement it keeps checking else if

Comment: Arrays are zero based, the correct index is `3`

Comment: Cannot reproduce: for me, the code works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a simple tracing here.

```
11 | 22 | 33 | 44 | 55 | 66 | 77 | 88 | 99

Target: 44
```

First step: `high = 8, low = 0`

```
low <= high
```

Enters the loop: `mid = 4`, `list[4] = 55`

```
Target < list[mid]
high = 3, low = 0
```

Second step: `high = 3`, `low = 0`

```
low <= high
```

Enters the loop: `mid = 1`, `list[1] = 22`
Here as mid is an integer fraction part is ignored during calculation

```
Target > list[mid]
```

Hence, `low = 2`, `high = 3`

Third Step: `high = 3`, `low = 2`
Again, `low <= high`, Enters loop: `mid = 2`, `list[2] = 33`

```
Target > list[mid]
```

Hence, `low = 3`, `high = 3`

Final Step:

```
low == high
```

Enters loop: `mid = 3`, `list[3] = 44`

```
Target = list[mid]
returns true
```